# Checking the limit of High-Volume Platform Events

Tags: limits, platform-event

We use platform events with Comet-D subscriber to synchronize two systems. Sometimes we reach daily limit of 50.000 published events (1.500.000/30 days) and sync process stops. At that point, we can't determine if that limit reached and when it will be reset.

Unfortunately, limits resource from REST API provides only monthly and hourly data which are not informative in our case (MonthlyPlatformEventsUsageEntitlement and HourlyPublishedPlatformEvents).

Please describe how we can determine that:

1. Daily limit excided - true/false
2. The limit will be reset at "particular time" (is it 24h since limit reached  or we just need to wait for the next calendar day?)
3. How many platform events remain until the limit will be reached again?

Thank you in advance for any provided suggestion

Comment: have you tried reaching out to your account manager to see if you can buy a higher limit?

Comment: The answer to [How to monitor Platform Events consumption?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/251831/102) suggests high volume events should use the monthly limit. Standard Platform Events can monitor the rolling 24 hour limit with `DailyStandardVolumePlatformEvents`